# Breaking from a for loop after adding to a vector

Tags: java, loops, vector, user-input, reverse

The goal of my program is to ask user to enter a sentence and then reverse the words in that sentence while using a vector.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseVector {

public static void main(String []args){

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   Vector<String> vec =new Vector<String>();
   String word = "";          

       System.out.print("Enter a sentence  :");

       for(int i=0;i<=vec.size();i++){          
               word=scan.next();                   
               vec.add(word); //adding each word to an element.              
       }

      Collections.reverse(vec);
      System.out.println(vec);                    
  }
}
```

I am looking for suggestions on how to break from the *for loop* once all of the words have been added to the vector.  My thought is some sort of *if statement* that states if there are no more words to add to vector then break.

The program should do the following:

```
Enter a sentence: The bird flew high
```

Output:

```
high flew bird The
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Vector. It's old and has unnecessary synchronization (which doesn't help). Use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [`scan.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read the entire line; this essentially uses the "newline" to indicate the end of the sentence.

Now you'll have a `String` containing the whole sentence. Then you can split the string into words with e.g. [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String sentence = scan.nextLine();
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); // <= sequence of one or more whitespace

for (String word : words)
    vec.add(word);
```

You could also use a second `Scanner` to read the words from the sentence string, if you'd like to stay away from the [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of `String.split()`, e.g.:

```
String sentence = scan.nextLine();
Scanner sentenceScan = new Scanner(sentence);

while (sentenceScan.hasNext())
    vec.add(sentenceScan.next());
```

The key there is `hasNext()`. You may be tempted to use `scan.hasNext()` on your original scanner but, unfortunately, this will not get the job done, as `hasNext()` will continue to return `true` until the end-of-file on the input is reached (and a newline input is not an end-of-file).

By the way, note that in your original code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=vec.size();i++)
```

Here, `vec.size()` is initially 0, so this loop would never execute anyways. One advantage of using dynamically sized containers (such as `Vector`) over arrays is that you can add elements to them as needed. So instead of looping to `vec.size()`, which couldn't be known ahead of time anyways (you don't know how many words will be entered), loop over all the input words and just `add()` them to the vector.

---

Attempting to break down the while loop in the second example as requested in comments. This while loop:

```
while (sentenceScan.hasNext())
    vec.add(sentenceScan.next());
```

Essentially this is a direct translation of the English sentence: "While there are more words, get the next word and add it to vec." It's always good when your code clearly reflects your intentions, but we can break it down a little to see how it works:

We know the following:

- [`while (condition)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loops while *condition* is *true*.
- [`sentenceScan.hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) returns `true` if it *can* get another word from the sentence, and `false` if it can *not* (i.e. if the end of the sentence string is reached).
- [`sentenceScan.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) will read the next word from the sentence string and return it. Internally, the scanner moves past this word when it reads it (it keeps track of its current position in the sentence string behind the scenes). So each time you call `next()`, it effectively grabs the next word from the string and "consumes" that word so the next time you call `next()`, it gets the following word. If you try and call `next()` when there are no more words, it will throw an exception (see linked documentation).
- [`vec.add(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28E%29) of course appends whatever to the end of the `Vector`.

So let's expand this like so:

```
while (true) { // loop "forever", since we don't know when we'll stop
    if (!sentenceScan.hasNext()) // if there are no more words... 
        break; // ...get the heck out of this loop!
    String word = sentenceScan.next(); // get next word from scanner
    vec.add(word); // add that word to the vector
}
```

For brevity we can skip some steps, for example, we don't really *need* that `word` variable since we only use it in one place, so:

```
while (true) { // loop "forever", since we don't know when we'll stop
    if (!sentenceScan.hasNext()) // if there are no more words... 
        break; // ...get the heck out of this loop!
    // get next word from scanner and add it to vector, in one fell swoop:
    vec.add(sentenceScan.next());
}
```

And since our condition for breaking out of the loop is simple, at the beginning of the loop, and based on a boolean value, we can just make it be the actual loop condition:

```
while (sentenceScan.hasNext()) { // loop until there are no more words
    // get next word from scanner and add it to vector:
    vec.add(sentenceScan.next());
}
```

And so we have the loop from that second example. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: I went with the second Scanner route and managed to get it to work.  I see how my vec.size loop was a silly idea to begin with. In my mind, I am trying to work through how the while loop is reading each word but it gets a little hazy.  Do you mind breaking the while loop down step by step just so I understand fully?  Thank you.

Comment: After staring at it long enough - pretty sure I got it.  Ha ;)  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @TroutmasterJ Too late! I already added an explanation to the answer. Good luck!